# How to find all the rows in table that follow a template?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have 3 tables.

table tag

```
id   tag_name     tag
1    date         [0-9]+([\.:;\-\/ ]?(ЪЬЪЬ)?[0-9]+[\.:;\-\/ ]?(ЪЬЪЬ)?)+
2    text         (.*)
```

table message

```
 id   group_number  msg                                  id_template 
 1    2             some text 25.06.2016 some more text  0
```

table template

```
 id   group_number  tag_text
 1    2             some{text} {date} {text}
```

where {text} can replace any text in msg and {date} can replace any date in msg.

In this case message with id 1 follows template with id 1, but there are many messages and templates.

So, for every message.msg that follows template.tag_text I want to insert in message.id_template template.id.

In sql it should look somewhat like

```
update message
set message.id_template = template.id
where message.msg like 'template.tag_text'
```

but I don't know how to deal with {date} and {text}, because this

```
some text 25.06.2016 some more text
```

and this

```
some{text} {date} some more {text}
```

would be considered different.

Is it possible with just sql?

Comment: MySQL's REGEXT works with bytes; it is unlikely to "do the wrong thing" with Cyrillic (`ЪЬЪЬ`).

Answer (score 0):

You need a `join` and to use the right comparison operator:

```
update message m join
       template t
       on m.msg regexp t.tag_text
    set m.id_template = t.id;
```

Note:  This will be slow (because it has to do a nested loop join).  Also, if multiple templates match, one is arbitrarily chosen for the id.

Comment: Do I need to replace regexp with my regular expressions?

Comment: @EugeneCuz . . . No.  `regexp` is an operator in MySQL.